# Matlab maximize function

Tags: matlab, maximize

I have a function that gives me a likelihood which I want to maximize. The problem is that I need to give 4 parameters that I need to estimate. I have this function:

```
[likelihood, z0, z1, z2, z3]= myfun(g, g1, g2, x1, g3, x2, x3)
```

that in output gives likelihood how can I maximize it? I know all the `g` but I do not know the `x` and I should estimate them with maximization of the likelihood. Moreover I do not know the `z` as well.

I guess I should do fminsearch but I could not find documentation with parameter estimation like this.

Answer (score 1):

`fminsearch` seems like it would do just fine here - you just have to make inputs that abstract the search problem in the way that function expects. Here I think this means creating a function that:

1. Takes the unknown parameters as a single array argument
2. Returns a value to minimize, not maximize

Assuming that `0` is a sensible initial value for all `x` parameters, this would look something like this:

```
x = fminsearch(@(x) -myfun(g, g1, g2, x(1), g3, x(2), x(3)), [0,0,0]);
x1 = x(1);
x2 = x(2);
x3 = x(3);
```

To find out the `z` values and resulting `likelihood` from the search result returned, you can then simply put the result back into `myfun`:

```
[likelihood, z0, z1, z2, z3] = myfun(g, g1, g2, x1, g3, x2, x3)
```

Comment: Correct - the inputs don't strictly have to be scalars lined up in a 1D array; they can be arranged in a matrix but the search will try to optimize every element in the matrix. Since in this case there is a prime number of values to optimize, a 1-by-7 array is your only option. You could organize the 7 values a little more concisely like this: `ss = fminsearch(@(ss) -kalcvf(y, lead, a, reshape(ss(1:4),2,2), b, H, diag(ss(5:7)), z0, vz0), zeros(1,7))`.

Comment: If you have the Optimization Toolbox then `fmincon` offers the kind of constraints you're looking for. I don't have the toolbox but it looks like your example would look something like: `fmincon(@(ss) -kalcvf(y, lead, a, reshape(ss(1:4),2,2), b, H, diag(ss(5:7)), z0, vz0), zeros(7,1), [[-eye(2);eye(2)] zeros(4,5)], [0;0;1;1])`. If you don't have it there are various strategies you can use with unconstrained search that are discussed online. Whether you use a purpose-built function or not, remember that searching a nonlinear function doesn't guarantee an optimal, or even good, answer on its own

Comment: You get that error because the number of elements you're extracting from `params` doesn't match the size of the matrices you're reshaping them into. To reshape `H` into a 9-by-2 matrix you need 18 elements, but `params(5:23)` has 19. Same for `reshape(params(24:145),11,11)`, you have one too many. But to answer your second question, 143 parameters is almost certainly way too many to get a good result in a sensible time frame. If a good result is achievable at all with unconstrained search, there are probably significantly more efficient ways of getting the same result.

Comment: If you mean to arrange array elements into an 11-by-11 symmetric matrix you could do this with `diag(params(23:33)) + squareform(params(34:88))`. Still may well not be a smart solution. Plenty of problems cannot be solved by trial and error of this sort; some are unsolvable or have no known solution and the rest require specific understanding of the governing mathematics to solve.

Comment: I would really want to understand what a Kalman filter does to be able to offer a meaningful suggestion.

Comment: The above specifies the initial values of `params` to be `100*eye(86)` which specifies the problem as an 86-by-86 matrix of parameters, with the parameters on the diagonal starting at 100 and the rest at 0. If you intended 86 parameters all starting at 100 then that argument should read `100*ones(1,86)`.

Comment: In that case it's exactly what it says. `-kalcvf(data_fk, lead_fk, a_fk, [params(1) 0; 0 params(2)], b_fk, reshape(params(3:20),9,2), [diag(params(21:31)) + squareform(params(32:86))])` needs to return a value for `params = 0.001*ones(1,86)` and for whatever reason does not. Knowledge of `kalcvf` is needed to understand what's wrong with those inputs.